# Displaying database table records in a predefined html table cells

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

I have a table called Table_I with 31 rows. I want to display each row into a predefined (existing) table with 31 cells. That is, each table row into each individual table cell.

```
 Table_I

      ID | Name  | Rowcol |
      .....................
       1 | ABC   |  3-1   | 
       2 | PQR   |  3-2   |      
       3 | XYZ   |  3-3   | 
       4 | MNO   |  3-4   | 
       5 | DEF   |  4-1   | 
       6 | QRS   |  4-2   |      
       7 | UVW   |  4-3   | 
       8 | IJK   |  4-4   |
```

Output:

```
Predefined table

    | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
    .....................................
    |  ABC   |   PQR  |   XYZ  |  MNO   |
    .....................................
    |  DEF   |   QRS  |   UVW  |  IJK   |
```

Code:

```
<?php

...Connection to DB...

$query="SELECT name, rowcol
        FROM  Teble_I
       ";

$params = array($_REQUEST['query']);

$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

if($results===false)
 { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }

if($results===false)
 { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }

$r=3; 
$c=1;

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { 

?>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
<tr>
<?php   
    if($row['rowcol']==$r ."-". $c) 
        {
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>";  
        }

    $c++;

    if ($r==3 && $c==5 || $r==4 && $c==5) 
        {
            $r++; 
            $c=1; 
        }

?>

 </tr> 
<tr>
<?php
    if($row['rowcol']==$r ."-". $c) 
        {
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."<td>";  
        }

    $c++;

    if ($r==3 && $c==5 || $r==4 && $c==5) 
        {
            $r++; 
            $c=1; 
        }
    }
?>

 </tr>

</table>
```

Expected Output:

```
    | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
    .....................................
    |  ABC   |   PQR  |   XYZ  |  MNO   |
    .....................................
    |  DEF   |   QRS  |   UVW  |  IJK   |
```

Help is really needed and appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connect to the database, query the database, loop through the results and prepare your output. I didn't include the code because I didn't want to confuse people reading this.

Comment: Haha @Typoheads... Thanks for your reply though. I already did the connection, database query and loop, but to no avail. I will modify the original question and include my present code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! I figured it out using an array. Below is how I did it:

```
    <?php

    ...Connection to DB...

    $query="SELECT name, rowcol
            FROM  Teble_I
           ";

    $params = array($_REQUEST['query']);

    $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

    if($results===false)
     { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }

    if($results===false)
     { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }

// set array
$array = array();

//select and display record from database
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 

    {
        // add each row returned into an array
          $array[] = $row;

    }

    ?>

    <body>
    <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $array[0]['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $array[1]['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $array[2]['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $array[3]['name']; ?></td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

I'm so excited!

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select ' + stuff(
    (
        select distinct ',max(case ID when ' + cast(ID as varchar(2)) + ' 
               then Name end) as [Cell ' + cast(ID as varchar(2)) + ']'
        from Table_I
        for xml path('')
    ),
    1, 1, ''
);
select @sql += ' from Table_I;'
execute(@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks Ullas. Honestly, I appreciate your response but I'm even more confused with your solution. I'm still new to PHP but doing everything to learn faster.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example which might suit your needs. `$data` is just for demo purposes, it should be your SQL data.

```
$data = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'Name' => 'ABC', 'Rowcol' => '3-1'],    
    ['ID' => 2, 'Name' => 'PQR', 'Rowcol' => '3-2'],
    ['ID' => 3, 'Name' => 'XYZ', 'Rowcol' => '3-3'],
    ['ID' => 4, 'Name' => 'MNO', 'Rowcol' => '3-4'],
    ['ID' => 5, 'Name' => 'ABC', 'Rowcol' => '4-1'],    
    ['ID' => 6, 'Name' => 'PQR', 'Rowcol' => '4-2'],
    ['ID' => 7, 'Name' => 'XYZ', 'Rowcol' => '4-3'],
    ['ID' => 8, 'Name' => 'MNO', 'Rowcol' => '4-4']
];

$finalData = [];
foreach($data as $row) {
    $position = explode('-', $row['Rowcol']);

    $finalData[$position[0]][$position[1]] = $row['Name'];
}
print_r($finalData);
$output = "<table>";
$output .= "<tr>";
for($i=1;$i<=count(reset($finalData));$i++) {
    $output .= "<th>Cell " . $i . "</th>";
}
$output .= "</tr>";
foreach($finalData as $row) {
    $output .= "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column) {
        $output .= "<td>" . $column . "</td>";
    }
    $output .= "</tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";

print $output;
```

`$finalData` will be a mapping array having an entry for each row and column:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => ABC
            [2] => PQR
            [3] => XYZ
            [4] => MNO
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => ABC
            [2] => PQR
            [3] => XYZ
            [4] => MNO
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks again @Typoheads. I modified my question. I hope it makes sense and you're able to help me again.

Comment: You're awesome @Typoheads !!! I tried it and it works, but the problem is the values in the table (`$data`) are values entered by the user from a form. They are not predefined.

I used :

`$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`

to fetch the table records.

Comment: Does the user enter the info in `Rowcol` too or just the data in `Name`?

Comment: No. The user only enters `Name`.

Comment: So what's the problem? Instead of `foreach($data ...)`use your `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

modifying your code:

```html
<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
<tr>
<?php   
$i=0
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    { 
            $i++;
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
            if ($i%4 == 0)
              echo "</tr><tr>";
 
    }

?>

 </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rkand, but the table is predefined. I tried something similar to your code before and it draws a new table for me instead of populating the cells in the html table already created.